# MCMCglmm with genomic relatedness matrix: "levels do not have a row entry in ginverse"

Tags: r, modeling, glm, mcmc

I am trying to estimate heritability of a quantitative trait using the animal model. Because I am studying a wild species of rodent, I lack pedigree information; instead, I am using a genomic relatedness matrix (GRM) using ~23,000 SNPs derived from ddRAD and estimated with PLINK/GCTA.

Although I have cross-checked the individuals in my GRM and my data file, I receive this error:

```
Error in MCMCglmm(trait ~ 1, random = ~ID, data = phens, ginverse = list(ID = gctaGRM),  : 
  some levels of ID do not have a row entry in ginverse
```

This problem is similar to one described previously: [MCMCglmm data format difficulties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107831/mcmcglmm-data-format-difficulties). In this case, the poster used a pedigree.

My data are as follows:

1. Data file with individual id, site, and phenotypic data, "phens"

```
> class(phens)
[1] "data.frame"

> head(phens)
    Site      ID       trait
1   QERC SGTm037  0.94770905
2 Robles SGTm038 -0.53410457
3   QERC SGTm039  0.35680224
4   QERC SGTm040 -0.24319776
5     MH SGTm041  0.02952266
6     MH SGTm043  2.25680224
>
```

2. Trait as a variable

```
> trait <- phens$trait # quantitative trait

> head(trait)
[1]  0.94770905 -0.53410457  0.35680224 -0.24319776  0.02952266  2.25680224
```

3. GRM from either PLINK or GCTA, read in using `gap` package: https://github.com/cran/gap/blob/master/R/MCMCgrm.R

```
gctaGRM <- ReadGRM('gcta-GRM') # reading in GCTA grm
plinkGRM <- ReadGRMPLINK('plinkgenome') # reading in PLINK PIHAT grm

> head(gctaGRM)

          SGTm037     SGTm038     SGTm039
SGTm037 1.0487960 0.000000000 0.000000000
SGTm038 0.0000000 1.065967000 0.009045295
SGTm039 0.0000000 0.009045295 1.032933000
SGTm040 0.1843918 0.000000000 0.019915070
SGTm041 0.0000000 0.031226350 0.000000000
SGTm043 0.0000000 0.038495810 0.000000000

> head(plinkGRM)

        SGTm037 SGTm038 SGTm039 SGTm040 SGTm041
SGTm037  1.0000       0       0  0.1345       0
SGTm038  0.0000       1       0  0.0000       0
SGTm039  0.0000       0       1  0.0000       0
SGTm040  0.1345       0       0  1.0000       0
SGTm041  0.0000       0       0  0.0000       1
SGTm043  0.0000       0       0  0.0000       0
```

As far as I can tell, the list of IDs in `phens` agrees with the columns and rows of IDs in either GRM. I can provide the full data files for those who are curious.

```
> head(phens$ID)
[1] SGTm037 SGTm038 SGTm039 SGTm040 SGTm041 SGTm043

# also played with changing phens$ID from factor to character; made no difference

colnames(gctaGRM)
[1] "SGTm037" "SGTm038" "SGTm039" "SGTm040" "SGTm041" "SGTm043"
```

This must be a formatting issue, and I spent a lot of time researching this on stack, google groups, and r documentation to no avail. Unfortunately, few resources cover how to implement GRMs in these models (though see https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0197720). I tried changing classes of my data file and trait, but this did not work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I received the same error, and like you I was puzzled because the rownames of the GRM did match what was in my data.

In my case, I fixed the issue by using a standard data frame instead of a tidyverse tibble for the `data` argument. MCMCglmm doesn't throw an error when a tibble is used for `data`, but unfortunately its internal data checks are coded in a way that doesn't work on tibbles.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for using gcta-based GRMs, though I haven't answered my exact problem as specified in my original post.

I found this older post: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2014q2/022217.html. I changed my gcta-based GRM (original class matrix) into class dgcMatrix and was able to run the model. This solves a different error I was receiving before I posted my original question:

`(Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : trying to get slot "Dim" from an object of a basic class ("matrix") with no slots)`

I would still be interested in understanding my original problem if anyone has an explanation or has solved a similar problem!